# Mechanical waves in a vacuum

Tags: waves

If mechanical waves cannot travel through a vacuum, why can a string wave travel in a vacuum? Or can a string wave travel through a vacuum?

Comment: Hint: The disturbance is propagating along the string, not the surrounding medium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm basically repeating what Chair said in a comment because it's the answer.

To quote [Wikipedia's page on mechanical waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_wave):

> A mechanical wave is a wave that is an oscillation of matter, and therefore transfers energy through a medium.

The vacuum of space has very limited amounts of matter very spread out, therefore it's a very poor medium for wave propagation.  A true vacuum has no medium, and would have no chance at propagating a wave (and even in a near vacuum, it's unlikely you will find much wave behaviour due to how spread the material is).

If you make a string move in a vacuum, it is still able to propagate a wave along itself because *the string* is the medium in this case.  Trying to make a wave travel through a vacuum is like trying to make a wave travel along multiple strings that aren't connected.  There's no good way for it to travel between.